# can't get CURL output

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl, soap

This is my php code.

```
<?php
$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soap12:Body>
<RequestList xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <category>syncapppr</category>
  <subcategory>put_app_presc</subcategory>
  <paralist>[{"app_List":[{"server_id":"","doctorid":"1266","patientid":"19569","prescriptionid":"870472109","parentid":"","parentserverid":"","FeesDue":"0","clinicid":"1273","caseno":"KAS-5712022016514","casetype":"","reason":"","note":"","diagnosis":"","adate":"22/07/2016","atime":"05:50 AM","fee":"300","refdoctorname":"","canceledbit":"false","rescheduledbit":"false","reschedule_reason":"","recschduledid":"","cancelled_reason":""}],"doc_id":"1266"}]</paralist>
</RequestList>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
"Content-type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
"Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
);
$ch = curl_init();
$fh = fopen('soap_response.xml', 'w'); 

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://fakeurl.com/webservices/desktopservices.asmx?op=RequestList');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100000000);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
//$xml = iconv("GB18030", "utf-8", $response);
$parser = simplexml_load_string(stripslashes($response));
$json = json_encode($parser);
echo($json);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

When i execute my script it give me error.

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\DsAdmin\call_1.php on line 41
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\DsAdmin\call_1.php on line 41
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\DsAdmin\call_1.php on line 41

but as you can see i am save CURL output to file too. and in that file i am getting correct output. i can't understand what is wrong in my code.

i had refereed many solution on net but nothing worked, so can some one help me here?

**File Output**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><RequestListResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><RequestListResult><syncapp_pres_list><SyncApp_Pres_Master><app_List><Appointment_Master><id>0</id><server_id>15238</server_id></Appointment_Master></app_List><startfrom>0</startfrom><endfrom>0</endfrom><clinicid>0</clinicid></SyncApp_Pres_Master></syncapp_pres_list></RequestListResult></RequestListResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

Comment: Did you try with one line XML ?

Comment: @tanaydin didn't get your question.

Comment: $xml_post_string has some new lines in it, maybe that causes problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

you are closing  ?php tag in this line. make it like...

```
$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"
```

Comment: no i am not closing  php tag, that whole string is between single quote(' '). and i am getting currect output in file

Comment: You can always escape it to \?\> just to make sure.

Comment: @Kalko i've done as you suggested but it didn't help me :(

Answer (score 0):

don't run `stripslashes` on the response, it will completely corrupt the xml. 
`rawurlencode` the `$xml_post_string` for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code but to no avail. The fakeurl you supplied doesn't work (thanks captain) and I can't tell what is the problem without having the output from it. The problem is in the cURL though, it's probably returning TRUE instead of a code (but that's what you asked in the first place)

I once had a problem with getting no cURL response and fixed it by setting CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to TRUE - without it you will return NULL on redirect, instead of the redirected page content.

I'd be glad to look more into the problem if you supply me with a working URL for the cURL.